# Unable to login to SQL Server using SSMS and SQL agent failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, connectivity

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 ENT insalled on Windows server 2008 R2 ENT. I am unable to login to SQL Server locally after the installation. Getting below error:

> Connection handshake failed. An OS call failed: (80090331)
>   0x80090331(The client and server cannot communicate, because they do
>   not possess a common algorithm.). State 56.

The error led me to this article and I updated my DB engine to 10.50.6542.0. But still unable to login. What should I do in order to allow my SSMS to connect locally. Also the second issue is SQL agent service is not starting. It fails with below error:

> Agent could not be started ( unable to connect to server (local),
>   SQLserveragent cannot start).

How to fix this as well? Below is my environment details:

- Windows server 2008 R2 Ent. SP1
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Ent (10.50.6542.0)
- .Net version 4.6.01055

**SCHANNEL Status:**

> SSL 2.0:  Client: DisabledByDefault = 1 Enabled = 0  Server:
>   DisabledByDefault = 1 Enabled = 0
>
> SSL 3.0:  Client: DisabledByDefault = 1 Enabled = 0  Server:
>   DisabledByDefault = 1 Enabled = 0
>
> TLS 1.0:  Client: DisabledByDefault = 0 Enabled = 1  Server:
>   DisabledByDefault = 0 Enabled = 1
>
> TLS 1.1:  Client: DisabledByDefault = 0 Enabled = 1  Server:
>   DisabledByDefault = 0 Enabled = 1
>
> TLS 1.2:  Client: DisabledByDefault = 0 Enabled = 1  Server:
>   DisabledByDefault = 0 Enabled = 1

Please let me know if you need any further details.

---

**Update:**

I made some progress on it. I installed ADO.NET - SqlClient (.NET Framework 3.5/.NET Framework 2.0 SP2) referring link https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3135244. I am now able to connect SQL server using SSMS locally and also able to start SQL agent service. Yipee.

But now the new issue is appearing. I can't connect the server remotely using windows authentication. I get below errors in windows eventviewer logs when I try to connect it. Also, no errors in SQL server error logs.

> Log Name:         System Source:         Schannel Event ID:      36888
>   Task Category: None  Level:          Error Keywords:        User:
>   SYSTEM Description: The following fatal alert was generated: 40. The
>   internal error state is 1205.   Log Name:       System Source:
>   Schannel Event ID:      36874 Task Category: None  Level:
>   Error Keywords:        User:         SYSTEM Description: An TLS 1.0
>   connection request was received from a remote client application, but
>   none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are
>   supported by the server. The SSL connection request has failed.

[image]

Comment: also see related question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742054/the-client-and-server-cannot-communicate-because-they-do-not-possess-a-common-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix for my this question was to apply

- .NET framework 4.6.1
- ADO.NET - SqlClient (.NET Framework 3.5/.NET
  Framework 2.0 SP2) from this link
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3135244.

These fixed the local login and SQL agent service issues. Then the new issue surfaced i.e. unable to SSMS this server from other servers.

To fix this I had to enable `‘KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Hashes\SHA’` in registry. After enabling it remote connection started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to disable SSL 3.0 and keep SSL 2.0 enabled, it worked for me while only TLS 1.2 was enabled

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. Could you possible supply more information on how to achieve the stated? The current answer is a bit short and doesn't supply enough information. Please consider reading [answer] and add more information to your answer by clicking on [edit]. Thank you.